# Como fazer SEO na prática

Tags: seo, sitemap

Tenho algumas duvidas de como praticar SEO. Provavelmente não serei so eu com essas duvidas. 
Eu sei que ha aqui muitos artigos sobre seo, eu fiz pesquisa pelo site e não fiquei nada esclarecido, porque na verdade, eu tenho duvidas mesmo é como fazer SEO na Prática.
Deixo em baixo algumas duvidas:

- Num site dinamico, como um blog, sempre que crio um post tenho que indexar manualmente os links no google webmaster tools?
- Como sei quando o link do meu post foi indexado no google?
- Submeto um sitemap.xml, passados alguns dias ele já esta desatualizado certo? Tenho que submeter esse sitemap com alguma regularidade ou o google vai fazendo varrimento de forma a manter-se atualizado?
- Que ferramentas/softwares gratis posso usar?
- Quando se fala em apostar numa Keyword, como é isso? Sempre que publico um post tenho que por a mesma palavra chave?
- Ridirecionamento 200? O que é? Como fazer corretamente?

Peço desculpa pela minha ignorancia, mas estou um pouco perdido.
Se alguem poder ajudar, eu agradecia imenso.

Obrigado

Comment: Eu acho melhor você fazer uma pergunta nova por duvida pois a resposta para isso viraria um livro.

Answer (score 3):

**Nenhuma das respostas atribuídas abaixo são a verdade absoluta. Tudo que perguntou depende de regras de negócio de cada Motor de pesquisa, são apenas percepções corriqueiras adquiridas dia a dia.**

> **Pergunta 1:**    Num site dinamico, como um blog, sempre que crio um
>   post tenho que indexar manualmente os links no google webmaster tools?

Não, de forma alguma. Geralmente se o domínio já existe a algum tempo ele já possuí backlinks externos apontados para ele. Naturalmente os bots das serps por algum meio terão acesso ao seu domínio e no processo de rastreamento de suas páginas acaba encontrando a url do novo post. No entanto isso pode demorar, se deseja tentar acelerar os processos de rastreamento, indexação e ranqueamento, pode lançar mão de um Sitemap para informar novas URLS que vem surgindo no seu domínio.

> **Pergunta 2:** Como sei quando o link do meu post foi indexado no google?

Isso é simples, basta ir ao google e digitar : `site:http://meudominio.com/pagina` se o resultado for listado é porque o processo de indexação da url já foi concluído. No entanto deve  entender que indexação e ranqueamento são procedimentos distintos, o fato de sua nova página estar listada na SERP, não quer dizer que está ranqueada com palavras chaves e recebendo tráfego.

> **Pergunta 3:** Submeto um sitemap.xml, passados alguns dias ele já esta
>   desatualizado certo? Tenho que submeter esse sitemap com alguma
>   regularidade ou o google vai fazendo varrimento de forma a manter-se
>   atualizado?

Como disse acima não importa que tenha ficado desatualizado, no momento que ele possuí alguns links de entradas (backlinks) ele vai correr o processo de rastreamento por todas as páginas do seu domínio independente de qual página de entrada se utilizou para acessar o domínio, até que o timeout definido por regras internas de negocio de cada buscador se esgote e ele saia. No entanto quanto maior a relevância do domínio nas serps, maior o tempo dedicado para se efetuar o procedimento de rastreamento para o domínio em questão e um dos fatores que defini a autoridade do domínio são links internos de entradas e links atribuídos de sites de terceiros. Esses são os famosos backlinks.

> **Pergunta 4:** Que ferramentas/softwares grátis posso usar?

O que quis dizer com isso ?

> **Pergunta 5:** Quando se fala em apostar numa Keyword, como é isso? Sempre que publico um post tenho que por a mesma palavra chave?

Ninguém cria um domínio sobre programação e fala de doces correto? Quando falamos em apostar em Keywords (palavras chaves) é porque existe todo um estudo feito em torno delas, para conhecermos seu volume de pesquisa, taxa de competição da Keyword, que defini uma média de quantos webmasters competem tentando conseguir a palavra chave, localidade aonde a palavra chave recebe o maior volume de pesquisa, entre muitas outras coisas. Cada página de seu blog deve ser denso sobre o conteúdo que está se tratando para demonstrar isso as SERPS definimos títulos com marcação HTML são os famosos H1...H6, além disso o titulo da página deve conter uma descrição abstrata do assunto focado nas palavras chaves trabalhadas no artigo, entre muitas outras coisas. Essas combinações de fatores é que torna a página uma pretendente a adquirir palavras chaves na serp. No entanto existe milhões de abordagens a serem estudadas na web, não basta abrir um post e escrever 500 mil vezes a mesma palavra que deseja obter, os mecanismos de pesquisa sabem analisar e separar o que é uma página com denso conteúdo e uma página praticando spam de tags.

> **Pergunta 6:** Redirecionamento 200? O que é? Como fazer corretamente?

Redirecionamento 200????? Isso existe!!! Eu conheço redirecionamento 301. O código 200 é o código atribuído pelo servidor de web a uma requisição de página bem sucedida, os redirecionamentos 301 são utilizados para migração de domínios ou páginas de um site. Sempre que se deseja efetuar a troca de um nome de domínio ou alterar a url de uma página (post), deve se utilizar um redirecionamento 301, quando se redireciona uma url utilizando 301 a relevância atribuída a página de origem é repassada pelas serps para a nova url. Sem danos ao tráfego que já adquiriu. É um indicativo as serps, que deseja trocar a url que hospedava um determinado conteúdo.

Como disse lá em cima, SEO é uma ciência não exata deve se utilizar não só as informações acima mas como também o próprio instinto e sensibilidade para conseguir boas posições.

Boa Sorte!

Comment: O sitemap, posso/devo submeter o mesmo sitemap varias vezes ou não é necessário? Se submeter será errado?

As keywords, nos posts, devo ter mais que uma keyword? Quantas?  Imaginando que o meu blog é sobre marketing digital, todas os posts devem conter a mesma, ou as keywords são unicamente focadas no conteudo do artigo e não do blog em geral?

Comment: Relativamente aos redirecionamentos, estou com alguns problemas no meu site. Imagine que tenho um link https://meusite.tld/top-rated/ (link correto), se as pessoas digitarem https://meusite.tld/top-rated (sem a barra no fim do link) retorna o erro 404 (not found), como posso evitar que isso aconteça? usando htaccess, que codigo devo criar?

Comment: O sitemap você pode e deve submeter várias vezes, ajuda porque você fornece novas formas de entrada para as SERPS, mais isso não é obrigatório. Sobre o redirecionamento se sua URL é com barra no final não pode ter duas urls diferentes para o mesmo conteúdo isso provoca duplicação de conteúdo. Se não está abrindo está correto. O que deve fazer é uma página de erro customizada 404 que dê ao usúario uma forma amigável de indicar caminhos quando ele acessar uma área inexistente.

Comment: Obrigado Rafael. Vou tentar analisar toda a informação que me passou.

Answer (score 3):

Vou dar respostas mais abrangentes, pois é impossível responder isso tudo sem links de Referência para você se aprofundar mais.

- Num site dinâmico, como um blog, sempre que crio um post tenho que indexar manualmente os links no Google webmaster tools?

  > Depende, no Wordpress por exemplo existe o plugin Yoast SEO que faz várias automatizações com Google Search Console. Aqui tem a documentação https://kb.yoast.com/kb/how-to-connect-your-website-to-google-webmaster-tools/
  >   Se quiser fazer na mão use o Add URL do Google https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url
- Como sei quando o link do meu post foi indexado no google? Submeto um sitemap.xml, passados alguns dias ele já esta desatualizado certo?

  > Aqui está a documentação oficial de como o Google trabalha com o SiteMap: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=pt-BR e pode usar no sitemap.xml `<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>` para falar para o Google que o site é atualizado uma vez por mês por exemplo. Aqui tem referencias sobre isso: http://utidasideias.com.br/blog/seo/sitemapxml-em-seo
- Tenho que submeter esse sitemap com alguma regularidade ou o google vai fazendo varrimento de forma a manter-se atualizado?

  > "*Se as páginas do site estiverem devidamente vinculadas, o normal será nossos rastreadores da Web conseguirem detectar a maior parte de seu site.*", **mas**
  >   "*O uso do sitemap não garante que todos os itens nele serão rastreados e indexados, pois os processos do Google têm como base algoritmos complexos para programar o rastreamento. No entanto, o sitemap beneficia o site na maioria dos casos, e você nunca será penalizado por usá-lo.*" Fonte: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=pt-BR
- Que ferramentas/softwares grátis posso usar?

  > Várias, procura no Google. Exemplos: **GTMatrix** https://gtmetrix.com/, **SEO SiteCheckup** https://seositecheckup.com/, **SEM Rush** https://www.semrush.com/
- Quando se fala em apostar numa Keyword, como é isso? Sempre que publico um post tenho que por a mesma palavra chave?

  > Por boas práticas vc deve usar apenas um  por página, e é interessante que as palavras usadas dentro dele se repitam no restante do conteúdo da página, inclusive na URL, ALTs, Links e textos, use tambén os H2, H3, etc.
- Redirecionamento 200? O que é? Como fazer corretamente?

  > Acredito que vc está se referindo ao **Redirect 301** "*Quando você digita uma URL em seu navegador, ele vai até o servidor web, onde a página esta hospedada, e tem a intenção de buscar o conteúdo que ali estiver. O servidor, por sua vez, retorna com um código para seu navegador. Normalmente este código é HTTP 200, que significa que sua página está ok e dessa forma o site é carregado normalmente.*"  O **Redirect 301** diz ao motor de busca que o conteúdo daquela página foi mudado de URL, porém com esse tipo de Redirect você mantem a **Autoridade Sobre o link** e não perde a relevância dele no Rank do Google, mesmo o seu conteúdo estando em uma nova URL. Link de referência: https://resultadosdigitais.com.br/blog/redirect-301/

> **Como fazer o Redirect**: Pode ser feito de várias formas com PHP, ASP, ou direto no .HTACCESS **Fonte:** https://www.agenciamestre.com/seo/redirecionamento-301-em-php-asp-htaccess-coldfusion-e-ruby-on-rails/